# How to pass value from controller to a function in model through index in yii2

Tags: gridview, model, controller, yii2

I have added an extra column in grid whose value is calculated by a function which is in model.
**Column in index file is**

```
       [
        'attribute' => 'Arrears',
        'pageSummary'=>true,
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->calculatearrears($model);
                    },
        ],
```

**function in model is**

```
public function calculatearrears($model,$month){

    return ChallanArrears::find()->select('total')
    ->Where(['challan_arrears.challan_id' => Challan::find()
    ->select(['MAX(id)'])->where(['month_year' => $month])
    ->andWhere(['sid'=>$model->sid])->groupBy('sid')])->scalar();
}
```

Now, I want to pass **month** value from controller to this function. 
My code in controller is

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $month = $request->post('month');

    $searchModel = new DetailfeereportSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'month' => $month,
    ]);
}
```

This value is accessible in index page but when I pass it in the function in index, it does not work. I tried to pass it as

```
[
        'attribute' => 'Arrears',
        'pageSummary'=>true,
        'value' => function ($model, $month) {
            return $model->calculatearrears($model, $month);
                    },
        ],
```

Error occurs **Undefined variable: month**
Please help me to guide may be I am trying to achieve my goal in wrong way. Or tell me how to access this value from controller and pass it to function through gridview widget

Comment: I have tried $this->month, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do that. First, modifying your code a little bit:

Your function in model:

```
public function calculatearrears($model,$month){

    return ChallanArrears::find()->select('total')
    ->Where(['challan_arrears.challan_id' => Challan::find()
    ->select(['MAX(id)'])->where(['month_year' => $month])
    ->andWhere(['sid'=>$model->sid])->groupBy('sid')])->scalar();
}
```

And in view file:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Arrears',
    'pageSummary'=>true,
    'value' => function ($model) use($month) {   // here use($month)
        return $model->calculatearrears($model, $month);
        },
    ],
```

**Or more OOP way**, first of all define property in your model and add to rules:

```
class YourModel extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public $month;

    public function rules() {
        return [
              // your rules
            ['month', 'string'],
        ];
    }
    //...
}
```

In controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    $searchModel = new DetailfeereportSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);  //here $month will be loaded, because it's now your model property

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

Change your function to:

```
public function calculatearrears(){

    return ChallanArrears::find()->select('total')
    ->Where(['challan_arrears.challan_id' => Challan::find()
    ->select(['MAX(id)'])->where(['month_year' => $this->month])
    ->andWhere(['sid'=>$this->sid])->groupBy('sid')])->scalar();
}
```

And in view file use it like:

```
 [
      'attribute' => 'Arrears',
      'pageSummary'=>true,
      'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->calculatearrears();
       },
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use use() for make visible $month to the clousure

```
 [
    'attribute' => 'Arrears',
    'pageSummary'=>true,
    'value' => function ($model) use($month) {
        return $model->calculatearrears($model, $month);
                },
    ],
```

and obviusly the function  calculatearrears must be adapted c for the required use eg:

```
 public function calculatearrears($model, $month){
      .......

 }
```

Comment: @scaisEdge, edit answer and add in `public function calculatearrears($model){` this variable, should be fine ;) Like: `public function calculatearrears($model, $month){`

Comment: Variable month is containing id of the row but not the actual value

Comment: Yeah, because you have to pass it by `use($month)`, second param in `function($model, $variable)` is row number. Change function in your model, pass it by `use()` and should be fine.